# Find the matrix that corresponds to the composite transformation of a rotation followed by a translation.

Tags: linear-algebra

Given an object's vertices, find the matrix that corresponds to the composite transformation of a rotation of $90$ degrees, followed by a translation by adding $(0,3)$ to each point.

I want to call the rotation matrix $A_1$ and the translation matrix $A_2$. Thus my composite transformation will look like $A_2A_1$.

The object's vertices are given as the following:

\begin{align}
A &= (-1,0)\\
B &= (1,0)\\
C &= (0,1)
\end{align}

Here is what I have done so far:

$$\text{For the rotation matrix $A_1$:}\pmatrix{x' \\ y'} = \pmatrix{\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta} \pmatrix{x \\ y}$$

$$\implies \pmatrix{x' \\ y'} = \pmatrix{\cos90 & -\sin90 \\ \sin90 & \cos90} \pmatrix{x \\ y}$$

$$\implies \pmatrix{x' \\ y'} = \pmatrix{0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0} \pmatrix{x \\ y}$$

This would mean that my $A_1 = \pmatrix{0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0}$. However, I think I'm supposed to use homogeneous coordinates for this problem. In other words, I should actually get something like this:

$$\pmatrix{x \\ y \\ 1} \rightarrow A_1 \pmatrix{x \\ y \\ 1} \rightarrow A_2 A_1 \pmatrix{x \\ y \\ 1}$$

This makes sense because I'll need $A_1$ and $A_2$ to be conformable to find my final answer $A = A_2 A_1$.

Answer (score 1):

Translation cannot be expressed a matrix acting on a vector. You could contrive the following "translation matrix", that translates by $(0,3)$:
$$
\left( 
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & \frac{y+3}{y} 
\end{array}
\right)  
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
x \\ y
\end{array}
\right)
= \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
x \\ y + 3
\end{array}
\right)
$$
But is dependent on the coordinates $(x,y)$ and is as such a nonlinear operator. To see that this is true, try composing the matrix twice and note that it doesn't result in a matrix that translates by $(0,6)$. Translation is a fundamentally different operation from rotation. The transformation you are looking for is a linear operation of the form:
$$
\boldsymbol{x}' = \boldsymbol{x}_0 + A\boldsymbol{x}
$$
where $\boldsymbol{x} = (x,y)$ and $\boldsymbol{x}_0 = (0,3)$ and $A$ is the rotation matrix you derived.